# Is it possible to pass props via React Komposer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I currently have my react-komposer set up like this:

```js
const composer = (params, onData) => {
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('comments');
  if (subscription.ready()) {
    const comments =  Comments.find({approved: true }, {sort: {timestamp: -1}}).fetch();
    onData(null, { comments });
  }
};

export default composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(CommentsList);
```

What I would like is to pass another selector to my find query which is based on the props of this component.

So I imagine it something like this:

```js
const comments =  Comments.find({approved: true, city: {activeCity} }, {sort: {timestamp: -1}}).fetch();
```

But that doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already managed to solve this problem. Turns out instead of using this.props I should have just used props instead.

This is the working code:

```js
const composer = (props, onData) => {
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('comments');
  if (subscription.ready()) {
   const activeCity = props.activeCity;
    const comments =  Comments.find({approved: true, city: activeCity }, {sort: {timestamp: -1}}).fetch();
    onData(null, { comments });
  }
};
```